# lodash 'includes' not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

I tried to use this function, but it's not defined ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5bgpov2/1/)).

```
console.log(_.include([1, 2, 3], 1));
console.log(_.includes([1, 2, 3], 1));
```

also I saw that 'include;' without 's' work well.
they have mistake in the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#includes)? or I missed something?
thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking at the docs for v.3.3.1 and including v.1.2.1 in your Fiddle.

`_.include` was renamed to `_.contains`, and that was later renamed to `_.includes`.
As of v.2.4.1, the rename to `_.includes` had not happened yet.

So use an updated version of lodash and all will be fine:

```js
console.log(_.include([1, 2, 3], 1));
console.log(_.includes([1, 2, 3], 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.4.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm experienced this in lodash-core 4.17.4. The solution was to use the full build instead of the core build.